# How to fix this? <div class="form-group">...</div>

Tags: cypress

This is the response error from running cypress.

> Timed out retrying after 4000ms: cy.type() failed because this element:
>
> ```html
> <input autocomplete="new-password" class="form-control" data-val="true"
>   data-val-           required="The User Name field is required." 
>   id="myform" name="UserName" placeholder="Enter username" 
>   required="required" type="text" value="">
> ```
>
> is being covered by another element:
>
> ```html
> <div class="form-group">...</div>
> ```

I have tried to use this code, but it still errors.

```js
cy.get('input[name="UserName"]').click({ force: true }).type('your-username')
cy.get('input[name="UserName"]').focus().type('your-username')
```

I would like to execute the command `type('your-username')`.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is indicating ***cy.type() failed***. If you look further in the message, it will tell you to use `{force:true}` option on that command.

But you have only used it on the click. The following should work:

```js
cy.get('input[name="UserName"]').type('your-username', {force:true})
```

You will not have to click or focus, Cypress already does that.

But you should try to pass the test without forcing, perhaps this is better (depends on the app)

```js
cy.get('input[name="UserName"]')
  .should('be.visible')
  .type('your-username')
```